# How do I configure a 404 error page in MODX?

Tags: php, modx

```
http://www.example.com/test1
http://www.example.com/test2
http://www.example.com/test3
```

all of these are non-existent pages and redirects to the index.php page, the search engines marks those links as duplicates, they return 200 ok, how to make them return 404 not found?

using modX cms

Answer (score 13):

By default, MODX serves up the home page when it can't find a page that matches the request if you haven't defined an error page.

Create a new resource to serve as your 404 page, then go to `System > System Settings`, search for `error_page` and add the ID of your error resource there.

MODX will then serve this resource for 'not found', automatically adding in the `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` header.

*Note: I'm assuming you're using MODX Revolution, but it's very similar for Evolution.*

Comment: This needs to be the top answer. The user specifically asks about ModX only.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you **own** those pages.

```
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit;
```

Comment: @Zecrow well if you have those pages, then there.

Comment: no i don't have those pages, they are just links to non-existent pages, but the server redirects them all to the main page, i need to make the server respond as 404 not found rather than 200 ok

Comment: No need to add headers and nothing wrong with the server. MODX handles 404s but in this case it hasn't been properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

it can be configured in System>system settings.
search by key "error".
put the value of your source 404.

suerte!